# App does not show up in the installed application list of the Sony smartwatch2 app

Tags: android, sony, sony-smartwatch

I have some problems with SmartWatch2:

1. Sony Xperia Z1:

   - Accessory Version:1.0.B.0.60;
   - Host Application Version:1.0.12;
   - Smart connect: 5.4.8.
2. Verizon Samsung galaxy note 2:

   - Smart connect: 5.4.8.

My two apps do not show up in the installed application list in Sony Smart Connect. I really don't know what to do!

Does anyone have problems like this and solved it?
Many thanks.

**Update**:
I use "Sony add-on SDK 2.0" and SmartExtensionAPI, SmartExtensionUtils from this pack as linked libraries in my apps. Also "Sony add-on SDK 2.0" marked as a target platform for apps.

**Update 2**:
Another user with SmartWatch 2 write me that my app didn't listed on his phone smart connect app list.

Comment: Have you tried restarting your device?

Comment: I get a little confused when you mention the Smart Connect version on your older phone, that should not be compatible with SmartWatch 2. What version of Smart Connect are you running on the Z1? And I guess you are using the latest SmartWatch 2 application (host app) from Google Play?

Comment: To Weston: Yes, users sad that thay restarted mobiles.

Comment: To Jerker: Both users said that they use latest version of Smart Connect for there phones. First user have sw1 and second sw2.

Comment: First user just said that my yesterday update (recompilation with sdk 2.0) helps him. So have only one problem with sony z1 and smartwatch2. This update didn't helps to him.

Comment: User info (Sony z1 + sw2): Accessory Version:1.0.B.0.60; Host Application Version:1.0.12

Comment: Smart connect: 5.4.8.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have tried the extension yourself on real HW and it works for you?  Couple things you can tell them to try:

1. Uninstall the extension and reinstall it.
2. Unpair the bluetooth connection to SW2 and re-pair it.

Comment: tried it but no use
but getting an error in the CONSOLE and no errors in logcat

couldn't find smartextensionapi.apk!
couldn't find smartextensionutils.apk

so i tried installing gmail from my phone and it got installed on to the smartwatch 2 as well

so what do i do now please reply

Comment: Sounds like a compile problem.  Are you able to even compile an APK for your app?  Try right clicking on your SmartExtensionAPI project -> Properties -> Android -> Under Library section make sure "IsLibrary" is checked.  Do the same for SmartExtensionUtils as well.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure:

1. Your SmartWatch2 extension gives the correct dimensions about itself
   (i.e. the dimensions of the SmartWatch2 screen)
2. Your application maps correctly those dimensions, and transfers the control to your
       extension

That was in case your extension never appeared on the SmartWatch2 screen. If it did, but does no more, restarting your phone normally helps. In more difficult cases, uninstall the SmartWatch2 app from your phone (it will be reinstalled once you pair your SmartWatch2 again).

Answer (score 0):

I have a similarly problem but related to the development process. I'm working on a control extension app for SW2, and I was able to compile the code and see the app on the SmartConnect Installed Apps and then test it in the real device (i.e. SmartWatch 2).

After a couple of iterations on Edit code > Compile > Test, the app stops to show on the SmartConnect App list and on the SmartWatch 2 too.

I don't understand why this happens and its not clear what is the solution for this. Rebooting, uninstall, etc. Its like a random try&error solution, and leads to o much time lost on getting the app running again.

Sony SDK Team should give one word on this...